# Re-configuring a data set

Tags: regex, r

I'm working on a class assignment currently and have created a pretty large data frame from some odd 500 jumbled text files. What I have currently in my large data frame is a column for Date, Latitude, Longitude, and a bunch of different weather readings.

I am given this .dat file which contains elevation data for a few Latitude and Longitude points, though the format is not how I need it in order to bind the relevant info to my data frame. The Longitude is in the column headers (when I use read.table()) and the latitude is in the "rownames" column.

[read.table(.dat)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0m7tv.png)

```
rownames 113.75 111.25 108.75
36.25   1526.75 1759.56 1948.38
33.75   612.94  1079.12 1979.31
31.25   328.62  1228.88 1483.69
```

Desired data frame

```
Longitude Latitude Elevation
113.75    36.25    1526.75
113.75    33.75    612.94
113.75    31.25    328.62
111.25    36.25    1759.56
111.25    33.75    1079.12
111.25    31.25    1228.88
108.75    36.25    1948.38
108.75    33.75    1979.31
108.75    31.25    1483.69
```

I want to change this into a data frame with columns for Latitude, Longitude, and Elevation reading so that I may add the corresponding elevation data into my larger data frame. I'm having trouble finding a function, or writing a regular expression that accomplishes this. Please let me know how I should proceed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `reshape2` pacakge to help melt your data. For example

```
dat<-read.table(text="rownames 113.75 111.25 108.75
36.25   1526.75 1759.56 1948.38
33.75   612.94  1079.12 1979.31
31.25   328.62  1228.88 1483.69", header=T, check.names=F)

long <- reshape2::melt(dat, "rownames")
long$variable<-as.numeric(as.character(long$variable))
long <- setNames(long, c("Latitute","Longitude","Elevation"))

long
#   Latitute Longitude Elevation
# 1    36.25    113.75   1526.75
# 2    33.75    113.75    612.94
# 3    31.25    113.75    328.62
# 4    36.25    111.25   1759.56
# 5    33.75    111.25   1079.12
# 6    31.25    111.25   1228.88
# 7    36.25    108.75   1948.38
# 8    33.75    108.75   1979.31
# 9    31.25    108.75   1483.69

str(long)
# 'data.frame': 9 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Latitute : num  36.2 33.8 31.2 36.2 33.8 ...
#  $ Longitude: num  114 114 114 111 111 ...
#  $ Elevation: num  1527 613 329 1760 1079 ...
```